# Encoding issue while spring message source using in idea

Tags: encoding, intellij-idea, internationalization, resourcebundle

I have resource bundle property file with following content:

```
OwnerImagesController.TerminalContentFormatIsNotAcceptable = \u0424\u0430\u0439\u043b \u0438\u043c\u0435\u0435\u0442 \u043d\u0435\u0434\u043e\u043f\u0443\u0441\u0442\u0438\u043c\u044b\u0439 \u0444\u043e\u0440\u043c\u0430\u0442
```

In idea configuration following file looks like

[image]

To convert my file for resource bundle compatible state I direcly use native2ascii.exe application from jdk.

It is not comfortable.

Please help to facilitate my property file usage

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation:

> It is possible to encode non-ascii symbols using both upper- and
>   lower-case hex symbols (e.g. '\u00E3' vs '\u00e3'). Upper case is used
>   by default. To use lower case, set 'idea.native2ascii.lowercase'
>   property in the bin/idea.properties file to true.

Source:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/editing-resource-bundle.html

It seems to be better than editing vmoptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable automatic conversion of non-ascii characters to appropriate escape sequences by checking *Transparent native-to-ascii conversion* in Settings/File Encodings (the section you show in the screenshot).

I also noticed that the the escape sequences in your snippet are lower case (i.e. `\u043b` instead of `\u043B`). IntelliJ converts them to uppercase by default. If you want to keep them lowercase to avoid unnecessary VCS changes, add following property to `idea.vmoptions`:

```
-Didea.native2ascii.lowercase=true
```